# Android: display passed data to second activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I send an arraylist to from my main activity to my second activity with the following code

```
ArrayList<String> RecipeNames = new ArrayList<>();
RecipeNames.add("Cake");

intentLoadNewActivity.putExtra("names",RecipeNames);
startActivity(intentLoadNewActivity);
```

And here in my second activity i get the arraylist.

```
ArrayList<String> names = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("names");
TextView Tname = findViewById(R.id.RecName);

// here I set a textView to be the string that arraylist contains.
Tname.setText(String.valueOf(names));
```

My problem is when I display the array I get "[Cake]" instead of "Cake"

How do I remove "[]"?

Answer (score 1):

You have a List of String objects but you're trying to display a single one when you're actually displaying multiple. If you want to display a single one, don't pass a List of String, just a String.

If you want to simply get a single String from the List of String objects you can do so with the following.

```java
String anyName = names.stream().findAny().orElse(null);

if (anyName != null) {
    // call setText
}
```

Comment: i save the string in another function. And i intent with another function. I can only send to the sender function my string with arrayList

Comment: ArrayList is just an implementation of List. Why can't you use getStringExtra() instead of getStringArrayListExtra()? If you're stuck with an ArrayList (List) why not just do what I said and get a single String from that list?

Comment: You are fcking awesome, i love you

Comment: Thanks, just press the ^ button and mark as the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

If you need to format the text before showing it on the screen you can use StringBuilder

Example:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (String name : names) {
  stringBuilder.append(name);
  stringBuilder.append(" ");
}
textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the braces, I think the following should serve your purpose.

```
Tname.setText(String.valueOf(names)
    .replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]",""));
```

Comment: A perfectly reasonable solution. However it makes more sense to give OP an understanding of why they're getting multiple values instead of a single one and how to handle it! Nonetheless, a reasonable solution.